# Google Places Autocomplete SearchBox: How to control (enable/disable) predictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

Is it possible to control (enable/disable) Google Places Autocomplete SearchBox (`google.maps.places.SearchBox`) service predictions?

Or in other words: is it possible to temporarily detach HTML input element from Autocomplete SearchBox service and then reattach it?

The thing is that I display service results just bellow HTML input element attached to SearchBox service. Problem is that after results are displayed and user focuses back on the input element, predictions are displayed over results and obscure their view. I would like to disable predictions until text in input element is changed by the user.

[image]

**EDIT 26/Aug/2016**:

Disable predictions is currently not supported by the Javascript API. Therefore I have just opened a feature request on Google. If you are interested in the feature please vote for it: [Autocomplete SearchBox - Control (enable/disable) predictions.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10367).

**EDIT 07/Sep/2016 - bounty award update**:

Thanks to all of you who participated in answering and also in promoting the question.

Primary objective of the award was to find solution using currently available means. I am afraid this did not happen so I decided not to award the bounty.

Although none of answers bellow provides a solution, each provides some sort of lead, so thank you! Maybe those leads will point to a solution in future.

Secondary objective of the award (although not communicated directly) was to promote [Autocomplete SearchBox - Control (enable/disable) predictions](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10367) feature request.  Its status changed to NeatIdea and has been assigned internal tracking number. It is a good sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution in AngularJS – it is extract from a directive.

`.pac-contained` is created after instance of an Autocomplete service is created, e.g.:  `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(…)` or `new google.maps.places.SearchBox(…)`.

What I do is to find just created `.pac-container` in the document, store its reference and mark that container as already processes (by adding an arbitrary class `.predictions-control` on it). "Marking" the container is needed only when more than one `.pac-container` is expected to be present in application.

Now with the reference I can control visibility (hide or show) of the `.pac-contained` with predictions.

```
// Container element with predictions.
var pacContainer = null;

/***
 * Find predictions container without predictions-control class set.
 * Then set  predictions-control class to it and convert it into
 * Angular's jqLite object.
 * @return {jqLite object} - container or null when not found.
 */
function getPredictionsContainer() {
    // Get div.pac-container without predictions-control class.
    var e = document.querySelector('div.pac-container:not(.predictions-control)');
    if (e){
        var container = angular.element(e);
        container.addClass('predictions-control');
        console.log('predictions-control: Container found.');
        return container;
    } else {
        console.warn('predictions-control: Container not found!');
    }
    return null;
} // getPredictionsContainer

/***
 * Loop in 50ms intervals until container is found.
 */
function untilContainerFound(){
    pacContainer = getPredictionsContainer();
    if (pacContainer == null){
        $timeout(untilContainerFound, 50);
    }
} // untilContainerFound

this.init = function() {
    untilContainerFound();
}; // this.init

/***
 * Prevent predictions to be displayed when user clicks on the
 * input element. It is achieved by adding ng-hide CSS class to
 * predictions container. Predictions container is identified by
 * ".pac-container" CSS class selector.
 */
this.hidePredictions = function() {
    // If predictions container was not found at directive
    // initialization try to find it now.
    if (pacContainer === null){
        pacContainer = getPredictionsContainer();
    }
    if (pacContainer){
        console.log('predictions-control: Hiding predictions.');
        pacContainer.addClass('ng-hide');
    } else {
        console.warn('predictions-control: Container not found!');
    }
}; // this.hidePredictions

/***
 * Show predictions again by removing ng-hide CSS class from
 * predictions container.
 */
this.showPredictions = function() {
    console.log('predictions-control: Showing predictions.');
    if (pacContainer){
        pacContainer.removeClass('ng-hide');
    }
}; // this.showPredictions
```

Call `init()` right after service instance is created:

```
// Create SearchBox service for auto completing search terms.
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox( inputElem[0] );
// OR
// autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( ..... );
autocomplete .addListener('places_changed', callback);

predictionsCtrl.init();
```

*Note:*
As long as it is guaranteed that two Autocomplete services are not created at the same time (e.g.: each service is on different tab) or can wait with creation of next service until `.pac-container` for previous service is found, it reliably works even with multiple instances of Autocomplete service.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is, After the user selects the place, you can add a class `disabled` to that input field.., This will help you enable/disable predictions based on class name.

And where you have the autocomplete code, you can wrap it within if else statement.

```
let field = document.getElementById('location');
if ( field.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1 ) {
  google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(field);
}
else {

  let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( field, {types: ['geocode']} );
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    let filed_val = field.value; // incase you need it
    field.classList.add('disabled');
  });

}
```

This will remove the autocomplete after user selects a place.. and later if you want, you can remove the `disabled` class from this field and it will work again.

Comment: I understand the sense of your example although you use `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` instead of `google.maps.places.SearchBox`. I do not like that it re-enables predictions by creating a new service object while the old one is still in memory.  Ideal would be to re-enable DOM event on the old object.

Comment: Exactly, Do what's ideal and suits your needs, This was just to show you one of the ways of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, or much point in having one: predictions are the whole point of [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox), its reason to be. If you don't want predictions, you can just use [Text Search in the Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests).

If the user clicks/focuses again on the search box, s/he probably didn't care for the results that get obscured by the suggestions. The same behavior is in Google Maps, and it's not an issue, is it?

If you can't put some space between the SearchBox and results (like in [this tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/)), and you absolutely must disable suggestions for a moment, I'd say you can destroy the `google.maps.places.SearchBox` object and create a new one later, attached to the same HTML input element.

Comment: It is for a mobile application, so screen space and number of keyboard clicks is at premium, that’s way I cannot move results bellow and want to use `SearchBox` service (`Text Search` is `SearchBox` without predictions). Destroying and re-creating  SearchBox service does not work.  Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly valuable information.

This is relevant around API V3.29 (not sure if it will always be accurate).
The div element that the API creates for the autocomplete has a class of "pac-container pac-logo".
Utilizing document.querySelector('.pac-container') you may be able to set it's style attribute to display: none on a click event elsewhere.

NOTE: When your users click back in the searchBox google will change the style attribute back to whatever is appropriate, so you only have to set it once, you shouldn't have to set it back again.

(this may be easier and cleaner than getting angular involved).

Hope that helps someone (I had to add a CSS rule to increase the z-index in an application to make the autocomplete show up)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the disabled attributed to the textbox this will disable predictions.

Using readonly attribute does not.

This may help in some circumstances.